# Re-rendering in my React sending email form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is for api re-rendering issue, I want to know that how to call one api after selecting a dropdown option.

Here it re-render infinite time after selecting an-option in drop-down. I call an client Api from client collection and show in client drop down after I select drop down and going to the infinite loop.

```
import Select from "react-select";
import Axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function Form() {
  const [hday, setHday] = useState(null);
  const [date, setDate] = useState(null);
  const [hdata, setHdata] = useState([]);
  const [hid, setHid] = useState(""); //changed use state value null to []
  const [client, setClient] = useState([]);
  const [clientvalue, setClientValue] = useState(null);
  const [clientId, setClientId] = useState(""); //changed use state value null to []
  const [cemail, setCemail] = useState([]);
  const [clientname, setClientname] = useState(null);
  const [clientEmail, setClientEmail] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [fromField, setFromField] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleRequest = async (e) => {
    if (clientvalue && hday && fromField && cemail && clientEmail && message !== "") {
      if (message !== "") {
        e.preventDefault();
        setLoading(true);
        console.log({
          clientvalue,
          hday,
          fromField,
          cemail,
          clientEmail,
          message,
        });

        const body = {
          clientvalue,
          hday,
          fromField,
          cemail,
          clientEmail,
          message,
        };

        await Axios.post("http://localhost:3002/mail", body, {
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
          },
        })
          .then((res) => {
            alert("Email Sent Successfully");
            setLoading(false);
            console.log(res);
            window.location.reload();
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            setLoading(false);
          });
      } else {
        alert("Compose Email");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Please fill all required filled");
    }
  };

  const fromFieldChange = (obj) => {
    setFromField(obj.target.value);
  };

  const handleQuillChange = (e) => {
    setMessage(e.target.value);
  };

  function handleHolidayChange(obj) {
    console.log("This is object country", obj);

    setHday(obj);
    setHid(obj._id);
    setDate(null);
  }

  //client call (repetadely call)
  const onChangeClient = (obj) => {
    console.log("client object", obj);
    console.log("client object id", obj._id);
    setClientValue(obj);
    setClientId(obj._id);
    setClientname(obj.client_name);
  };
  // console.log("This is client id and name", clientId + " " + clientname);

  //(issues repetadely execute)

  async function emailClick() {
    const url = `http://localhost:3002/api/getClientEmail/${clientId}/${clientname}`;
    Axios.get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        const temp = response.data.map((e) => e.email);
        setCemail(temp);
        console.log("Client Email", cemail);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  emailClick();

  const changeDate = async function dateClick() {
    const url = `http://localhost:3002/api/holiday_date/${hid}`;
    await Axios.get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        // console.log("This is holiday date",response.data[0]['date_of_holiday']);
        setDate(response.data.date_of_holiday);
        // console.log("holiday year",date);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  changeDate();

  useEffect(
    () => {
      async function getHoliday() {
        const url = `http://localhost:3002/api/holidays`;
        await Axios.get(url)
          .then((response) => {
            setHdata(response.data);
            console.log("this is holiday", response.data);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
      getHoliday();

      async function getClient() {
        const url = `http://localhost:3002/api/client`;
        await Axios.get(url)
          .then((response) => {
            setClient(response.data);
            console.log("this is client", response.data);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
      getClient();
      ///api/emailtemplates
      async function getClientEmail() {
        const url = `http://localhost:3002/api/emailtemplates`;
        await Axios.get(url)
          .then((response) => {
            setClientEmail(response.data.map((e) => e.subject));
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
      getClientEmail();
    },
    [date],
    [cemail],
  );
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleRequest} method="post">
      <div className="form">
        <div className="form__wrapper">
          <div className="form__title">
            {/* title */}
            <h4>Holiday</h4>
          </div>
          <div className="form__container">
            <div className="form__containerItems">
              <div className="form__containerItem">
                <div className="form__containerItemName">
                  <label>Client</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form__containerItemField">
                  <Select
                    onChange={onChangeClient}
                    placeholder="Select Client"
                    value={clientvalue}
                    options={client}
                    getOptionLabel={(x) => x.client_name}
                    getOptionValue={(x) => x._id}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form__containerItem">
                <div className="form__containerItemName">
                  <label>Holiday</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form__containerItemField">
                  <Select
                    onChange={handleHolidayChange}
                    placeholder="Select Holiday"
                    value={hday}
                    options={hdata}
                    getOptionLabel={(x) => x.holiday_name}
                    getOptionValue={(x) => x._id}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form__containerItem">
                <div className="form__containerItemName">
                  <label>Date</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form__containerItemField">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="date..." defaultValue={date} />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form__container">
            <div className="form__containerItems">
              {/* from */}
              <div className="form__containerItem">
                <div className="form__containerItemName">
                  <label>From</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form__containerItemField">
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="Sender Email.."
                    // autoFocus="autoFocus"
                    value={fromField}
                    onChange={fromFieldChange}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              {/* to */}
              <div className="form__containerItem">
                <div className="form__containerItemName">
                  <label>To</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form__containerItemField">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Client Emial.." defaultValue={cemail} />
                </div>
              </div>
              {/* Subject */}
              <div className="form__containerItem">
                <div className="form__containerItemName">
                  <label>Subject</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form__containerItemField">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Write your Sub..." defaultValue={clientEmail} />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form__containerItem">
                <div className="form__containerItemName">
                  <label>Compose Mail</label>
                  <button
                    disabled={loading}
                    onClick={handleRequest}
                    type="submit"
                    className="btn btn-info"
                  >
                    Send
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form__containerItem">
                <div className="container__composeMail">
                  <textarea
                    value={message}
                    onChange={handleQuillChange}
                    className="quill"
                    placeholder="Enter Content from here..."
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `emailClick();` and `changeDate();` in your function at all?

Comment: emailClick() is for geting email from the email-contacts collection by using client_id from getClient() Api, and changeDate() is for selecting date from date collection by using Holiday_id  from getHoliday() Api.

Comment: You're unconditionally calling them in your function, which is not good.

Comment: yes, please guide me

Comment: Unfortunately it's hard to tell what your form should really be doing, but there are lots of things technically wrong with it, starting with the use of `defaultValue` without any change handlers... The naming of your variables doesn't help much either. Hid? Hday? Hdata? Cemail + clientEmail? Why is an email an array? Why is the value for "subject" `clientEmail`? Etc.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).